# Run Time Error: cannot find module "ionic-native"

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, backand

I'm trying to connect ionic 2 app to backand and getting this run time error:

> Cannot find module "ionic-native".

I have tried running `npm install @ionic-native/core --save` – but does not help. Many thanks

> Set Up Details Are Here: Ionic Framework: 3.0.1 Ionic App Scripts:
>   1.3.0 Angular Core: 4.0.0 Angular Compiler CLI: 4.0.0 Node: 6.10.1 OS Platform: Windows 10 Navigator Platform: Win32 User Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
>
> Error: Cannot find module "ionic-native" at g
>   (localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7133) at Object.module.exports
>   (localhost:8100/build/main.js:114616:7) at webpack_require
>   (localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object.
>   (localhost:8100/build/main.js:86362:73) at webpack_require
>   (localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object.
>   (localhost:8100/build/main.js:140153:70) at webpack_require
>   (localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at
>   localhost:8100/build/main.js:66:18

`Package.Json` as follows:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "@types/node": "7.0.13",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "1.4.29",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "myApp: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you will need to see, but any help appreciated

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file? Never put your question on the comment section.Please remove that and put that with your original post.

Comment: Hi, it wouldn't let me paste all of it in the original comment because it has links in it apparently. Quite new to using stackoverflow. How do I get the package.json file? I realise this is a bit of a rookie question probably

Comment: This is sample `package.json` file? So what is your one? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Thanks Sampath, have added it into the question

Answer (score 1):

This issue is associated with the old import 'ionic-native'

in my case :
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
I removed and added the new :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen

If this is also your case, do not forget to add also in the module provider

Answer (score 0):

With Ionic 3, the ionic-native modules are now loaded as providers. See below links:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-native-3-x/

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/commit/62088

So, you have to upgrade your code if you want to use any of the native features.

Comment: Thanks, so do I need to upgrade to ionic 3? I think I am using version 2.2.1 a the moment

Comment: Looks like you already are on v3. Make sure you have followed the upgrade instructions mentioned in the links.